Nextjs cookies not setting
I have a nestjs backend and useing nextjs for my FE I need to set a cookie when my JWT expires, but notting I have done looks to be working. This is my route.ts code
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export interface IRefreshToken {
  accessToken: string,
  refreshToken: string
}

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const body = await req.json() as IRefreshToken;

  cookies().set({
    name: 'test', value: 'test', httpOnly: true,
    path: '/',
  })
  // Return the response to the browser.
  return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Cookie set successfully!' });
}

this is my page code
import { ITasks } from '@/interfaces/task.interface';
import { getTasks } from '@/request';
import { INTERNAL_API_URL } from '@/utils/endpoints.utils';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default async function Tasks() {
  const res = await getTasks();
  const tasks = res.data as ITasks[];
  const c = await fetch(`${INTERNAL_API_URL}/api/auth`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(res.tokens),
  });
  const m = await c.json();
  console.log(m);

  return (
    <main>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <div key={task.id}>
          <h2>{task.title}</h2>
          <p>{task.description}</p>
          <Link href={`tasks/${task.id}`}>go to task</Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}

my log return Cookie set successfully! but it is not show up and when i try to read it it comes back as undefined. I have tried a bunch of things but nothing works any ideas?

Try to set cookies to the NextResponse Header.
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers);
  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
    headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
 // Add your Cookie Here
 const cookiesValue = "";

 response.cookies.set("test", cookiesValue);
 // Add the Success Message to the response here....
return response;
}


Thanks for the suggestion but Route Handlers in the Next.js App Router do not support using the NextResponse.next() method to forward to the next Middleware.

Hi @user2411628, got any walkthrough for your solution?

you are calling your api in server component and in nextjs we can't set cookie on server components as per there docs
